# To execute azure CLI command as post build action in Jenkins job

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created git repository for Azure ARM linked templates , which create some resource stack using Azure cli command. But It needs to be build via maven command , then whatever json parameter and template files get generated , we upload it to Azure blob storage (as this is requirement for Linked template). then we fetch these template and parameter files from Azure blob storage , then execute cli command to deploy azure stack.

During build step, following commands are executed:

```
mvn clean install
mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="dev"
mkdir parameters
mkdir resourcetemplates
cp target/classes/parameters/dev/*.json parameters
cp target/classes/resourcetemplates/*.json resourcetemplates
```

And in post build action, i am using Azure Storage plugin to upload it to blob storage.
Now, i need to execute azure cli command , as below, but problem is i am not getting Azure-cli plugin option in post build actions in  dropdown list in jenkins.

```
az group deployment create --resource-group rg-test --template-file .\masterazuredeploy.json  --parameters templateBaseUrl=https://test.blob.core.
windows.net/azurestackautomationtest/resourcetemplates/  parameterBaseUrl=https://test.blob.core.windows.net/azurestackautomationtest/parameters
```

I dont want to create another Jenkins job and to execute it as post build action. As i have N environments for which i need to create this job, so it will create N*2 jobs, which i dont want.

Any other solution to execute azure cli command as post build step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Azure CLI](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+CLI+Plugin) plugin is available in the Jenkins Marketplace, and can be used only as a build step and not as a post-build action.

To work around this, you may convert the "upload to blob storage" part also as a build step instead of a post-build action, so you can use the [az storage blob upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload) command from Azure CLI, and then execute the aforementioned CLI step as well.